# Correctness of algorithm to calculate maximal independent set

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I am trying to find the maximal set for an undirected graph and here is the algorithm that i am using to do so:

1) Select the node with minimum number of edges
2) Eliminate all it's neighbors
3) From the rest of the nodes, select the node with minimum number of edges
4) Repeat the steps until the whole graph is covered

Can someone tell me if this is right? If not, then why is this method wrong to calculate the maximal independent set in a graph?

Comment: Do you want a *maximal* independent set (one that cannot be increased in size without removing a node) or a *maximum* independent set (one whose size is largest among all the independent sets in the graph?)

Comment: I want the maximal set, not the maximum set. In the first step, I select node with least number of nodes just to maximise the output, but I do not need the maximum. I could have selected any random node as well

Comment: This may be more suited to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I just wanted to make sure that I was analyzing the algorithm you described correctly.

Comment: @WaleedKhan- cstheory is more for research-level questions in CS.  This question would be a good fit for SO or for cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described will pick a maximal independent set.  We can see this as follows:

1. **This produces an independent set.** By contradiction, suppose that it didn't.  Then there would have to be two nodes connected by edges that were added into the set you produced.  Take whichever one of them was picked first (call it u, let the other be v)  Then when it was added to the set, you would have removed all of its neighboring nodes from the set, including node v.  Then v wouldn't have been added to the set, giving a contradiction.
2. **This produces a maximal independent set.** By contradiction, suppose that it didn't.  This means that there is some node v that can be added to the independent set produced by your algorithm, but was not added.  Since this node wasn't added, it must have been removed from the graph by the algorithm.  This means that it must have been adjacent to some node added to the set already.  But this is impossible, because it would mean that the node v cannot be added to the produced independent set without making the result not an independent set.  We have a contradiction.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is not one definite maximal independent set in any graph; take for example the cycle over 3 nodes, each of the nodes forms a maximal independent set. Your algorithm will give you one of the maximal independent sets of the graph, without guaranteeing that it has maximum cardinality.

On the other hand, finding the maximum independent set in a graph is NP-complete (since that problem is complementary to that of finding a maximum clique), so there probably isn't an efficient algorithm.

Comment: I think the question is whether the algorithm will find *a* maximal independent set, not *the* maximal independent set.

Comment: I realized that I didn't properly answer his question just now, edited :)

Answer (score 0):

After your clarify situation in comments, your solutions is **right**.
Even better, according to Corollary 3 from this paper http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2011/Lectures/lecture_7.pdf
your get *good* aproximation for subset order.
`Greedy gives a 1 / (d + 1) -approximation for (unweighted) MIS in graphs of degree at most d`